# I am trying to re-size a container: col-2 registered users.

Tags: template, layout, css, login

When landing on http://designozstudio.com/magento/index.php/customer/account/login/ there are 2 buttons: 'login' and 'create account'. The login button is in a block or container and the width is 376px, it should be a simple task to resize this to 485px however I cant find where to make the changes. Is anyone able to point me in the ringht direction?

Comment: Did you find an answer here? Please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3):

The width is defined in `styles.css` on line 1581:

```
.buttons-set .button{ float:left; width:104px; height:39px; background:url(../images/btn.png) no-repeat 0 0; margin:0 0 0 28px;}
```

What you want is to add your own css file:

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>directory/file.css</stylesheet></action>
```

And in that template, add the appropriate override css:

```
#login-form .buttons-set .button { width: 485px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the HTML: Activate template hints and you'll exactly see where this button is defined.

The problem is you image is too small and only available in that one width: http://designozstudio.com/magento/skin/frontend/theme1/default/images/btn.png
So you may have to rework the layout to create a dynamic width button.

Comment: This can be changed in css - don't edit the template for a css change. Keep presentation data out of your view files.